# Is it fair to be held up to mockery for preferring to run "mvn clean install" as 2 commands?

Tags: performance, maven-2

One of my team mates was held up for mockery by the team leads for preferring to run maven as:

```
$ mvn clean
$ mvn install
```

The discussion by the team leaders was about efficiency and speed of work & someone brought up the issue that person X is continuing to split

```
$ mvn clean install
```

into 2 separate commands. I know, I know that **life is unfair** but why would something so innocuous be an impediment to project progress. Would this be an issue for you in your team ?

Comment: We prefer to mock the color of each other's bikeshed.  http://bikeshed.com/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Dude, you've got serious team-leadership and more generally team-cohesion issues.  The bananoseconds that *might* possibly be "wasted" by running maven twice are nothing, but what this episode suggests about human relationships in the team is *big*, and sad.  Where's management? Are they aware of this? Would they even **care**? Depending on such issues, my advice might be to print out your resume on the *good* printer -- hiring is warming-to-heating up again (at least in Silicon Valley), and sticking with a dysfunctional team is not necessarily a necessary evil to keep putting bread on the table...!

Comment: Team leader want to promote good pracises but if it was in mockery form it means that he/she is good as programmer but not as a teacher.

Comment: Agreed Alex, and while I think making a mockery of someone is not on, and it might only save 5s over a days work, having an attitude that lends itself to efficient work from even the most trivial of things is a good thing imo.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the real issue is why people on your team are using mockery against each other.  That sort of thing is unprofessional and bad for morale in the long run.

Comment: Show me a team that never pokes fun at each other and I'll show you a team that doesn't truly work together.

Comment: There's a difference between poking fun and "mockery," with the cruelty and humiliation that the latter implies.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that's a pretty dumb thing to harp on.

Heck, I still prefer to type 3 command rather than doing `./configure && make && make install`.

Answer (score 1):

How many time clean task take? If long (I had a project with lot of small files and slow hard drive and clean taks takes more than 30s) you gain that time (including installing) and you can switch to other tasks.

I think that your team leader want to learn you good practices (maybe in a bad example). Assuming `mvn install site` is much better than `mvn install` and then `mvn site`.

It seams that you can replace word compiling with ....

[image: compiling]

In my opinion if you type less and/or improve your life, that's worth to be done. Read about [Kaizen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaizen).

Answer (score 1):

Mockery is kid-stuff. Pros know that no two people do things exactly the same.

Like in a marriage, if you can't live with the way she/he puts away socks, and you can't negotiate a middle ground, you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I don't know much about Maven, I'll grant you that. But I do know something about code.

Code evolves. This is code.

You write code for clarity, and with at least one eye on maintainability. Unless the difference between separating those commands and not separating them evaluates to a significantly measurable performance impedance, separate them for the sake of maintainability and extensibility.

Comment: Actually, these are command lines. So, not a maintenance issue.

Comment: Unless they are scripted, no?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are plenty of answers about the politics involved in mocking and receiving that mocking, but I'm actually writing with a technical defense of the question.

Running clean & install in two steps is often helpful.  I often do this because clean runs very fast for most maven projects, even large ones.  Running clean by itself is a quick way to make sure the project structure is "OK" before proceeding.  For this reason, it makes a very convenient gating command either by hand or with a one-liner, e.g., `mvn clean && mvn install`.

The speed improvement for a project of any size has to be negligible either way.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the 'mocked kid' might be doing a better job. In an ideal world, one would run the 'install' command only if the 'clean' command completed successfully. Something like `mvn clean && mvn install` would be even better and save precious picoseconds + typing time.

Of course, I have no clue whether mvn actually *returns* 0 if the command was successful. And doing an install after a clean means that there might be stale files *and* that the install process doesn't put things where they are supposed to go. But I digress.

Furthermore, you might want to resign and move away from such a workplace as soon as possible. If I were that kid, I'd implement an alias so that `mvn clean install` wipes your $HOME clean if typed as a single command. Just as a revenge.